# What's wrong with the following code? The database is not updated

Tags: java, android

Heres is update method is DatabaseHelper

```
public void updateFavorite(String p_name, String n_fav, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_FAVORITE,n_fav);
    String updateQry = KEY_FAVORITE + " LIKE ?";
    String string[] = {p_name};
    sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues,updateQry,string);
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
}
```

And here is my code in activity

```
s_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String fav;
                fav = uEdName.getText().toString();

                    databaseHelper = new DatabaseAccess(ReceiveDataActivity.this);
                    sqLiteDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    databaseHelper.updateFavorite(KEY_FAVORITE,fav,sqLiteDatabase);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"set 0",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //finish();
                }
        });
```

The database doesn't update the database.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `KEY_FAVORITE` as `p_name`, so (if `KEY_FAVORITE` is `"FAVORITE"`) your query ends up being

```
FAVORITE LIKE FAVORITE
```

which probably isn't what you meant.  To fix it, correct the parameters to your `updateFavorite` call.